# ADSI Library/Control for .NET

Tags: c#, active-directory, adsi

Is there an ADSI Library out there for .NET/C#? I have been able to find bits and pieces of code to do some tasks but nothing comprehensive.

I'm looking for a library that I can just drop into my code and run without having to do too much customization? I'm thinking something along the lines of [MEMM for Excel](http://www.iquinox.nl/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For .NET 1.x, there's really only the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace - not much more, unfortunately. That's your basic `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` classes, and that's about it.....

.NET 2.0 added the `S.DS.ActiveDirectory` namespace to handle structural objects like forests, domains, and so forth a lot easier. Check out this MSDN article [New Ways to Manage Active Directory using the .NET Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188700.aspx) on how to leverage those new capabilities.

For .NET 3.5 and up, there's a new `S.DS.AccountManagement` namespace which makes working with principals (users, groups, computers) a lot easier. Again, for an excellent intro, read this MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx).

Hope that helps a bit!

Marc

Comment: Guess I'm rolling my own :-) Thanks for the links and information.

Answer (score 2):

You have all that you need in .NET in the `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` assembly.  There is a large set of samples on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx).