# Assign variables to powershell using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, variable-assignment, pipeline

I'am tring to call a powershell script and pass through a parameter. I would all so like to pass through a more than one parameter eventually

```
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
        runspace.Open();
        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

        String scriptfile = "..\\..\\Resources\\new group.ps1";

        Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile, false);

        CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("test3");

        myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);


        pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
        Collection<PSObject> psObjects;
        psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();
```

The problem seems to be ... well nothing happens. Is this how to correctly assign the varibles? Giving test powershell script

```
# creates group
net localgroup $username /Add
# makes folder
#mkdir $path
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question so much as a quick comment - have you tried interacting with the local ADSI store through .NET instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640022/adsi-library-control-for-net

Comment: No never through of it, but thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of code:

```
CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("test3");
```

Creates a parameter named `test3` that has a value of null.  I suspect you want to create a named parameter e.g.:

```
CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter("username", "test3");
```

And you're script needs to be configured to accept parameters e.g.:

```
--- Contents of 'new group.ps1 ---
param([string]$Username)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The PowerShell script needs to be setup to accept parameters:

Try adding the following to the top of that script and re-testing:

```
param([string]$username)
```

Alternatively, you could add the folowing line to the top of your script:

```
$username = $args[0]
```

Good luck.

Comment: this helps but is assigning System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.CommandParameter as groupname

Comment: If you open up PowerShell and execute the script with that parameter, what happens?

Comment: Take a look at Keith's answer.  Looks like an issue with your C# and how you're setting the parameter.